# ProgressDialog acting strange in AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

i have the following code to load a file from my website

```
class DownloadTT4FileTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

                    private Context mContext;
                    private String  mFilename;
                    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
                    String  retString="";

                    public DownloadTT4FileTask(Context context, String filename) {
                        mContext=context;
                        mFilename=filename;
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void onPreExecute() {
                        Log.d("DownloadTT4FileTask", "onPreExecute");
                        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(mContext, mFilename, "Loading. Please wait...");
                    }

                    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

                        URL url;
                        try {
                            url = new URL(args[0]);
                            java.net.URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
                            con.connect();
                            //Log.d("DownloadTT4FileTask", "con.connect ok ");

                            java.io.BufferedReader in = new java.io.BufferedReader(new java.io.InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
                            String line;
                            for (; (line = in.readLine()) != null; ) {
                                // just read the line and save it
                                retString += line+"\n";
                            }   

                        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        return retString;
                    }

                    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                        Log.d("DownloadTT4FileTask", "onPreExecute");
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                };
                // loading from website
                filename = "http://2112design.com/tabs/"+band+"/"+song+".tt4";
                String fileContents = new DownloadTT4FileTask(context, filename).execute(filename).get(15L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

                br = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(fileContents));
```

it loads fine (about 5 secs to load) but the progress dialog is a bit off. it doesn't show up on the screen at the start of the download. it briefly flashes on screen at the end of the task.

i've seen many examples of how to use this and it looks like this is pretty normal code.

maybe the context is the issue? i get that from an onChildClick that running in a fragment which isn't the main activity. i tried using the main activity context but that just crashed.

```
    @Override
public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
    Globals.mDoc.OpenTT4Document(parent.getContext(), band, song, mRemoteFilesThis==null ? Doc.SDCARD : Doc.WEBSITE);

    return false;
}
```

any ideas? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as Doc says about [AsyncTask.get()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#get%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) :

> Waits if necessary for at most the given time for the computation to
>   complete, and then retrieves its result.

currently you are calling AsyncTask.get() on main UI thread and progress dialog not appeared . you will need to start AsyncTask without calling get() method as :

```
new DownloadTT4FileTask(context, filename).execute(filename);
```

and update UI after doInBackground completed inside onPostExecute as :

```
                protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                    Log.d("DownloadTT4FileTask", "onPreExecute");
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                     // get result here
                    br = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(result));
                }
```

**EDIT :**

if you want to call get method of AsyncTask then use a Thread to get result back and avoid freezing of UI as :

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
     try {
            Your_Activity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

               progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(Your_Activity.this, 
                 mFilename, "Loading. Please wait...");
            }
           });
              // start AsyncTask here
              String fileContents = new DownloadTT4FileTask(context, filename)
                                     .execute(filename).get(15L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

              Your_Activity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                 public void run() {
                    // update UI elements here
                     br = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(fileContents));
                       progressDialog.dismiss();
                  }
              });
          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
          } catch (ExecutionException e) {
             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
               e.printStackTrace();
          } catch (TimeoutException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
               e.printStackTrace();
          }
       }
 }).start();
```

Comment: thanks for the quick answer. i would rather process the results of the download in my main thread. i wonder it there is a way to do the execute without the get then wait in the main thread until the asynctask is done, then get the return value?

Comment: @steveh : it's not possible to get result back without calling get() method of asynctask . see my edit answer if you are calling asynctask.get() from UI main thread then u will sure need to call it inside a Thread to avoid freezing of UI  and use runOnUiThread to update UI from Thread after getting result back  as in my answer i have suggested already

Comment: thanks, i just pasted your code in but it complains about all the params not been final, and i can't make them final because some are function args.

Comment: @steveh : just make all parameters class level fields by declare it before onCreate of Activity

Comment: by the way, i'm not too concerned about getting the results back. i can pass the String fileContents to the constructor of the task and do doInBackgroud write to it. i tried just running the task and waiting for a few secs in the calling thread with Thread.sleep(5000) but the progress thing still didn't show up

Comment: @steveh : in my answer EDIT section

Comment: @steveh : honestly tell me my answer is helping u or not otherwise i im going to delete it .Thanks

Comment: sorry, my bad, i didn't realize you were the one posting the answer. i understand your code but i can't get it to build because all the params i pass to it like context, filename etc, its says have to be final, but i can't make them final. i'm pretty new to java

Comment: @steveh : then make it class level variable by declaring it before onCreate of Activity as i told u already

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23761/discussion-between-steveh-and--k)

Answer (score 0):

i figured it out with the aid of ρяσѕρєя K, thanks

the basic problem was i wasn't returning from the onChildClick  that started the loading thread so doing ProgressDialog.show didn't really do anything until the thread was finished and by then there was no point to it,

so what i do now is start the asynctask without the get and do all the processing for the read data in onPostExecute. so i can return from my load function right away, back to the UI thread and the progress things shows.

BUT the thing is, i have no new document to display in main UI so i show and empty one with a title "waiting for blah blah blah...". when the load is complete i invalidate my main view and the doc shows up.